# How to parse/decode raw Netflow data to text in Java?

Tags: netflow

I want to convert raw Netflow traffic data to human readable format in java. Does any one have any clue how to achieve this.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which Netflow protocol version and which flow generator/exporter do you want to process data for?